# Oh, the felinity? Felixity?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, latin

My sister sighed "Oh, the humanity!" But she was talking about her cat. What is the right word if it's a cat?

Felinity?
Felixity?

Extra points for dogs...

Caninity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "Felinity". "Felixity" isn't an English substantive.

In Latin "cats" translates to "feles" (nominative).
They are classified as "Felidae", whereas we are "Hominidae".

"Caninity" describes the state of being a dog, as does "felinity" for cats.

> **felinity** (noun): `The feline quality; the quality of being cat-like in manner or disposition.`
>
> [The Century Dictionary](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=03&page=398&query=felinity)

Example usage:

> "Whatever our merits when compared with lower species, however, we vary conspicuously when compared with one another. Humanity is superior to equinity, **felinity**, caninity; but there are degrees of humanness."
>
> *Perkins — Concerning Children*

"Humanity" not only conveys our nature, but also our collective, the world's population (as in "Humanity will thrive!").

So, if you mean to describe the very particular *feline aspect* of something, then "Oh, the felinity (of it)!" seems like a good fit.

Comment: This would be a great answer if it cited sources. ;)

Comment: @Davo Added citations. Hope the format is befitting. Read https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer but couldn't find a common scheme for citations.